# How to place a txt file in a Java Project?

Tags: java, io

I have a text file that I am trying to read from using a BufferedReader however I'm not sure where I should place this text file in my Java Project and also what that directory would be called.

For example:
    File file = new File(*Directory that needs to be specified*);

Comment: Put it anywhere and provide the path in the command line? Put it on the classpath and read as a resource? I mean, there are a lot of options that fit what little you've said.

Comment: Most style/structure guidelines would tell you to either put it in a res folder or something similar.

Comment: How are you building and packaging your project? If you're using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), then put it under the `src/main/resources` folder. Another common option is to store (and read) files relative to the user's home folder (`System.getProperty("user.home")`).

Comment: @Dave Newton I guess I wasn't clear enough, I'm using eclipse and I'd like to store the text file with the java project instead of having it at an external directory. Right now I have the text file sitting in my src folder  and I am trying to associate the File I've made in my program to that text file

Comment: @GaryFishell First, understand that resources which are "embedded" internally to the project/Jar are no longer "files" and can not be referenced as such, instead you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`.  Where you place them is up to you, but you should consider the context of the resource.  If it's a "global" resource, it might be better placed in a something like `/resources` and based on it's context, in a sub folder. If it's a local resource of a specific class, it might be better placed within the same package as the class

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood you are not sure where is your root directory, put your file in you project home directory instead of /src . For example if your project is called MyProject, put your file in .../MyProject/myfile.txt and your relative path would look like this: `File file = new File("myfile.txt");` 
If you want your file in separate folder put it for example in /MyProject/resources/ and then your path would look like this:
`File file = new File("/resources/myfile.txt");`

Comment: I tried putting this file in the root directory of my project and specified my File as File file = new File ("myfile.txt"); and I still get a FileNotFoundException when trying to use this file later in my program